# Ansible run playbook only for hosts that match some variables

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that I want to execute on RHEL 6 servers only. I know I can put

```
when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == 6
```

Into every single task within the whole playbook, but that seems pretty inefficient to me.

Isn't there a way to limit whole playbook to these machines so that I don't have to put this line into every single task?

I suppose it would even execute much faster, because it wouldn't need to check if server is RedHat 6 in every single task.

Also, I assume that most performance-wise efficient way would be to store a list of RHEL 6 servers aside and execute this playbook on them only, as Ansible isn't really caching this information, so it would always have to connect to all servers just to figure out whether they are RHEL and version 6?

Comment: There is a good answer below, but you are correct that the best way would be to track the OS in inventory as groups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `include` with `with_first_found`:

```
- include: "{{ include_path }}"
  with_first_found:
   - "{{ ansible_distribution }}.yml"
   - "{{ ansible_os_family }}.yml"
   - "default.yml"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: include_path
```

Update: added `loop_var` to prevent possible `item` variable collision.

Answer (score 1):

One strategy to deal with this problem is to include a task file with the task specific for a distribution version like this in the main task file:

```
- include: "{{ ansible_distribution }}-{{ ansible_distribution_major_version }}.yml"
```

The file `tasks/RedHat-6.yml` would than contain all tasks specific for RHEL6.

When you want to your playbook to fail when the distribution is not supported you could do something like this:

```
- include: RedHat6.yml
  when: ansible_distribution == "RedHat" and ansible_distribution_major_version == 6

- fail:
    msg: "Distribution not supported"
    when: ansible_distribution != "RedHat" or whatever conditions you want
```

Comment: That's neat, is there a way to catch "unknown distribution" so that ansible doesn't produce some sort of file not found runtime error and fail everything?

Comment: Maybe something like this: `- include: unknown_distribution.yml when: not {{ ansible_distribution }} is defined`. But I'm not sure what Ansible returns when it failed to determine the distribution.