# How do I set Ansible to use whatever package manager is on the OS?

Tags: ansible, package-managers

I know Ansible has modules for `aur`, `apt`, `dnf`, `yum` and probably others. [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63668940)]

Is it possible for me to make an ansible recipe that checks what manager the system is using, and use that? How could I configure it to do that?

---

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Ideally, I would also be able to set what the package names are for that manager.

Comment: You can use https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/package_module.html, but you would lose almost all of the customization parameters for the module.

Comment: You could [identify the system package manager](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/46081/), register the result and use tasks based on that. Ansible has already variables for system distribution if facts are gathered which you can just use. You need only to define the behavior you like.

Comment: You could [run a playbook based on `ansible_distribution`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60140478/), [run playbook only for hosts that match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39525840/) or [run certain types of Ansible tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60631883/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the special variable `ansible_pkg_mgr` and the `when` task conditional to control which package manager module is used. For example:

```
    - name: Upgrade all packages
      ansible.builtin.yum:
        name: "*"
        state: latest
      when:
        - ansible_pkg_mgr == "yum"

    - name: Upgrade all packages
      ansible.builtin.apt:
        upgrade: yes
      when:
        - ansible_pkg_mgr == "apt"
```